# How does my textbook come up with this statement? I don't believe it to be true.

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

My textbook (*Introduction to Algorithms*) states the following:

[image]

---

When polynomially comparing $n^\epsilon$ and $lgn$, it states that $n^\epsilon$ is polynomially greater for any positive $\epsilon$. Does it mean for positive *integers*? Because in the case of $\epsilon = 0.1$, we have $n^{0.1}$ compared against $lgn$. Is $lgn$ not polynomially larger in that case?

Also, nowhere that I see in the book elsewhere does it state to assume $\epsilon$ is an integer. In fact, above that there's an example where $\epsilon$ is 0.2, so I don't think that assumption is being made.

Should it read that $\epsilon$ is an integer? Or am I not understanding polynomial comparisons?

Comment: No, for any positive real $\epsilon$, $x^\epsilon > \log x$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment: take the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^\epsilon}{\log x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \epsilon x^\epsilon = \infty.$$

Therefore for some $n$, $\frac{x^\epsilon}{\log x} > 1$ for $x>n$, so for $x > \max(1,n)$, 
$$x^\epsilon > \log x.$$